# Given $f(it)=t^3+t^2+t+1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given $f(it)=t^3+t^2+t+1$
I have to determine whether polynomials $f(-it)$ $f(it)$ $f(t)$ $f(-t)$ are linearly dependent or independent with respect to **real** and **complex** fields. Answer is that it is linearly independent with respect to $real$ and $complex$ fields.I solved this kind of exercises with vectors and matrices but not sure how to start this one can you help?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Best to check first over complex field. Consider the linear combination $k_1f(-it)+k_2f(it)+k_3f(t)+k_4f(-t)$ where $k_i\in\Bbb C$. Is there a choice of $k_i$ not all zero that makes this linear combination (polynomial) zero for all $t$?

Comment: I am not sure given $f(it)$ how can I find $f(t)$. I mean if given $f(it)=t^3+t^2+t+1$ why this doesn't depend on $i$? Sorry if this is silly question.

Comment: Well, keep $it=z$ which gives $t=z/i=-iz$ and substitute throughout the polynomial. $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is a constant.

Comment: Hint: $f(t)=f(i(-it))$

Answer (score 1):

I'll give some guidance. You should find hints such as @zwim's give$$\begin{align}f(t)&=1-it-t^2+it^3,\\f(it)&=1+t+t^2+t^3,\\f(-t)&=1+it-t^2-it^3,\\f(-it)&=1-t+t^2-t^3,\end{align}$$of which $1,\,t,\,t^2,\,t^3$ are linear combinations with unique coefficients, some of them **non-real** complex numbers. You should compute the coefficients to verify the bold part to answer the over-$\Bbb R$ problem. The crux is$$\sum_{n=0}^3i^{mn}=4\delta_{m0},\,m\in\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for giving time can you make more concrete how you found for example $f(t)$?.

Comment: Using the known linear independence of $1,t,t^2,t^3$ leads to many proofs (+1). Essentially equivalent to this is the observation that the coordinates of this family of polynomials w.r.t. that basis form a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: @HrantBaloyan I just did what zwim did: $f(t)=f(i(-it))=1-it+(-it)^2+(-it)^3$ implies the other cases.

Comment: @J.G. Side note : regarding your meta post , the questions you have chosen to answer today were chosen well. You may liberally use the search box to narrow your search and find questions where your service will be desirable and impactful, but otherwise in line with the [Enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) you are doing good. We will continue to send polite reminders if you find yourself answering a PSQ, but I see you are trying to be more careful, thank you very much for taking that much care.